# Ordering records with e.g. drag& drop, how does that look in a clean way?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, drag-and-drop

I have no clue how to achieve this, I tried for hours now. I implemented a drag&drop of a list and now I want to save the change of the order in my db. I think for this is an order field needed which stores an int. But the problem is: how should I populate this field?

E.g. I want to do an operation like "insert a new list item after item at position 2", i would define a value higher than that of position 2 and lower than that of position three. But this is limited somehow.

An idea was to write new order values for each record when changing one to keep a clean order value. But that seems odd because it is slow as hell.

How do good systems solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, this is what you want

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=462

Comment: thanks, this is an even better method. But it's also re-saving every record to keep a clean order. I think this has to do the job for the beta version.